# Not able to unmarshal XML for Go structure

Tags: xml, go, unmarshalling

I'm trying to write a piece of code in golang which takes an xml and Unmarshall it.
I'm pretty sure that I've done something wrong at the end  of my structure but I can't figure out what.
So I would appreciate if someone can help me by telling why the printed rate doesn't have any value, and how I could fix this issue.
Thanks a lot!

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type DataSet struct {
    XMLName     xml.Name    `xml:"DataSet"`
    Header      Header      `xml:"Header"`
    Body        Body        `xml:"Body"`
}

type Header struct {
    XMLName         xml.Name    `xml:"Header"`
    Publisher       string      `xml:"Publisher"`
    PublishingDate  string      `xml:"PublishingDate"`
    MessageType     string      `xml:"MessageType"`
}

type Body struct {
    XMLName         xml.Name    `xml:"Body"`
    Subject         string      `xml:"Subject"`
    OrigCurrency    string      `xml:"OrigCurrency"`
    Cube            Cube        `xml:"Cube"`
}

type Cube struct {
    XMLName         xml.Name    `xml:"Cube"`
    Date            string      `xml:"date,attr"`
    Rate            []Rate      `xml:"Rate"`
}

type Rate struct {
    XMLName         xml.Name    `xml:"Rate"`
    Currency        string      `xml:"currency,attr"`
    Rate            string      `xml:"Rate"`
}

func main() {
    myxml := `<DataSet xmlns="http://www.bnr.ro/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bnr.ro/xsd nbrfxrates.xsd">
    <Header>
        <Publisher>National Bank of Romania</Publisher>
        <PublishingDate>2020-05-07</PublishingDate>
        <MessageType>DR</MessageType>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <Subject>Reference rates</Subject>
        <OrigCurrency>RON</OrigCurrency>
        <Cube date="2020-05-07">
            <Rate currency="AED">1.2169</Rate>
            <Rate currency="AUD">2.8874</Rate>
            <Rate currency="BGN">2.4666</Rate>
            <Rate currency="BRL">0.7820</Rate>
            <Rate currency="CAD">3.1747</Rate>
            <Rate currency="CHF">4.5825</Rate>
            <Rate currency="CNY">0.6303</Rate>
            <Rate currency="CZK">0.1779</Rate>
            <Rate currency="DKK">0.6466</Rate>
            <Rate currency="EGP">0.2838</Rate>
            <Rate currency="EUR">4.8242</Rate>
            <Rate currency="GBP">5.5241</Rate>
            <Rate currency="HRK">0.6373</Rate>
            <Rate currency="HUF" multiplier="100">1.3776</Rate>
            <Rate currency="INR">0.0589</Rate>
            <Rate currency="JPY" multiplier="100">4.1970</Rate>
            <Rate currency="KRW" multiplier="100">0.3648</Rate>
            <Rate currency="MDL">0.2510</Rate>
            <Rate currency="MXN">0.1852</Rate>
            <Rate currency="NOK">0.4349</Rate>
            <Rate currency="NZD">2.7048</Rate>
            <Rate currency="PLN">1.0618</Rate>
            <Rate currency="RSD">0.0410</Rate>
            <Rate currency="RUB">0.0606</Rate>
            <Rate currency="SEK">0.4545</Rate>
            <Rate currency="THB">0.1380</Rate>
            <Rate currency="TRY">0.6161</Rate>
            <Rate currency="UAH">0.1668</Rate>
            <Rate currency="USD">4.4695</Rate>
            <Rate currency="XAU">243.2582</Rate>
            <Rate currency="XDR">6.0847</Rate>
            <Rate currency="ZAR">0.2406</Rate>
        </Cube>
    </Body>
</DataSet>`

    var currencies DataSet
    // we unmarshal our byteArray which contains our
    // myxml content into 'currencies' which we defined above
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(myxml), &currencies)
    if err != nil {log.Fatal(err)}

    for i := 0; i < len(currencies.Body.Cube.Rate); i++ {
        fmt.Println(currencies.Body.Cube.Rate[i].Currency)
        fmt.Println(currencies.Body.Cube.Rate[i].Rate)
        if currencies.Body.Cube.Rate[i].Currency=="EUR"{
            fmt.Println("EUR rate is: " + currencies.Body.Cube.Rate[i].Rate)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This might help you - https://golang.org/src/encoding/xml/example_test.go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing **Rate** struct to this :

```golang
type Rate struct {
    XMLName    xml.Name `xml:"Rate"`
    Currency   string   `xml:"currency,attr"`
    Multiplier string   `xml:"multiplier,attr"`
    Rate       string   `xml:",chardata"`
}
```

And I often use this site to convert **XML** to **Go struct**. You can try it too: https://www.onlinetool.io/xmltogo/